# Does a permanent magnet AC motor use reactant power?

Tags: power, motor, induction-motor, reactance

I'm learning about reactant power in school, I one thing I was told is reactant power is used to create the magnetic field and induction motor needs. Does this mean that a permanent magnet AC motor does not use any reactant power?

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/191177/2028